# Count how many elements of a type and return for a view MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, group-by

here is my problem:
I have a Database where I have a table device that has some devices, and each devices has a type.
I want to make a view to see how many devices of each type I have in the table.
What I have till now is, in controller:

```
public ActionResult Stock()
{
    var device = db.Device.Where(s => s.Status.ToUpper().Contains("Stock")).GroupBy(d => d.DeviceTypeName);
    return View(device.ToList());
}
```

In the view I have:

```
@model IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<System.String, Mobile_Inventory.Models.Device>>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
        DeviceType
        </th>
        <th>
            Qt
        </th>

@foreach (var item in Model) {

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Key)
        </td>
    <td>

    </td>


</tr>
}

</table>
```

But this way I can only see the Type of device and not the quantity.

I tried to change the var device to have the quantity:

```
var device = db.Device.Where(s => s.Status.ToUpper().Contains("Stock")).GroupBy(d => d.DeviceTypeName).Select( d => new
    {
        Type = d.Key,
        Count = d.Count()
    } );
```

But this way I return an anonymous type to the view and get the error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType2`2[System.String,System.Int32]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,Mobile_Inventory.Models.Device]]'.

Don't know how I can change the Model type for the view accept the Anonymous type, and don't know if it is even possible. Anyone can help, with a solution?

Comment: Use a Tuple? Instead of an anonymous type, just use a Tuple<string, int>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a ViewModel like this:

```
public class DeviceGroupViewModel
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Then, change your Action to this:

```
public ActionResult Stock()
{
    var devices = db.Device.Where(s => s.Status.ToUpper().Contains("Stock"))
          .GroupBy(d => d.DeviceTypeName)
          .Select(d => new DeviceGroupViewModel
          {
              Type = d.Key,
              Count = d.Count()
          }).ToList();

    return View(devices);
}
```

And, in your View, you'll have:

```
@model IEnumerable<Mobile_Inventory.ViewModels.DeviceGroupViewModel>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
        DeviceType
        </th>
        <th>
            Qt
        </th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Type)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Count)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Then, select it as the correct answer, so other people know that the question has been answered.